# why $viewValue === $modelValue on select?

Tags: angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/iVvvdbvI3it7KrYZW6mK

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.selectModel = '1';
  $scope.inputModel = new Date();
  $scope.testOptions = [
    {key: '1', description: 'text 1'},
    {key: '2', description: 'text 2'},
    {key: '3', description: 'text 3'}
  ];
});
```

.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form name="inputForm">
      <strong>how $viewValue works for input</strong><br />
      <input type="date" name="input" ng-model="inputModel"/>
      <div>$viewValue: {{inputForm.input.$viewValue}}</div>
      <div>$modelValue: {{inputForm.input.$modelValue}}</div>
    </form>
    <br /><br /><br />
    <form name="selectForm">
      <strong>how $viewValue works for select</strong><br />
      <select name="select" ng-model="selectModel" ng-options="item.key as item.description for item in testOptions"></select>
      <div>$viewValue: {{selectForm.select.$viewValue}}</div><!--shows '1', i expected 'text 1'-->
      <div>$modelValue: {{selectForm.select.$modelValue}}</div><!--shows '1', as expected-->
    </form>
  </body>
```

In the above plunker, you can see different meaning of $viewValue for input vs select.

For input, $viewValue is the string user is seeing, $modelValue is data model.

For select, $viewValue and $modelValue are equal, both being data model. 
That does not make any sense to me. Why is that?

**To clarify, my question is about select element, specifically: where does $viewValue come from (it seems to always equal $modelValue), and why it isnt actual text displayed in select element?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nature of `$viewValue` is determined by the directive. The `$render` method brings the view value to the screen and if the user can change a value, the directive converts the user's input to the view value. How that happens is completely up to the directive.

The default implementation of `$render` e.g. is empty. The implementation for `input` simply sets the value of the element:

```
element.val(ctrl.$isEmpty(ctrl.$modelValue) ? '' : ctrl.$viewValue);
```

That's why `$viewValue` is equal to the value that is being displayed. The implementation for `select` is more complex because you have a lot of options (pun intended). When you use `ng-options` the HTML that's generated is like this:

```
<option value="0" selected="selected" label="text 1">text 1</option>
<option value="1" label="text 2">text 2</option>
<option value="2" label="text 3">text 3</option>
```

As you can see the actual value is a simple index, barely related to your model. Furthermore the `selection` tag allows multiple selections. So you have several different possibilities as to what the view value is. I guess it was easiest to let `$viewValue` be equal to the model value.

FWIW: Imagine a custom directive that uses `ng-model` but does not directly display a value, like a custom slider. It makes perfectly sense to not use a separate view value but simply use the model value.

Answer (score 1):

`$viewValue` is the `inputElement.value` which is provided by the browser. 
As the input type is Date angular's built-in `ngModel` parsers will parse the `$viewValue` will convert it to date and then assign it to model. 
Code snippet from AngularJS

```
ctrl.$parsers.push(function(value) {
         if(ctrl.$isEmpty(value)) {
            ctrl.$setValidity(type, true);
            return null;
         }

         if(regexp.test(value)) {
            ctrl.$setValidity(type, true);
            return parseDate(value);
         }

         ctrl.$setValidity(type, false);
         return undefined;
      });
```

Comment: When talking about <select> element, $viewValue is not equal to element.value. In fact, (see updated plunker) value is equal to index of selected item.

Comment: With `ng-options` that are provided select is rendered as:
`<select>
<option value="0">text 1</option>
<option value="1">text 2</option>
</select>`
In this case the value of the select will be 0/1/2 ... Hence the `$viewValue` is printed as index of the array.